# Testing 409 conflict in flask-potion

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, pytest, flask-potion

I'm trying to test that a ModelResource of flask potion conflicts on creation if a one with the same id is present:

```
class Device(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'device'
    uuid = db.Column(UUID, primary_key=True, default=lambda: str(uuid4()))
    make = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=False)
    model = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=False)
    category = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=False)

class DeviceResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Device
        id_converter = 'string'

    class Schema:
        uuid = fields.UUID(io='wr')
```

and the testing is done as a pytest yield fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def application():
    flask_app = create_app()
    # return a webtest.TestApp
    test_app = TestApp(flask_app)
    test_app.current_app_context = flask_app.app_context
    return test_app

@pytest.yield_fixture(scope='function')
def single_device(application):
    obj = Device(**DEVICE_JSON)
    with application.current_app_context():
        db.session.add(obj)
        db.session.commit()
        yield obj
        for device in Device.query.all():
            db.session.delete(device)
        db.session.commit()

def test_create_device_fail(single_device, application):
     response = application.post_json('/api/v1/device', params=DEVICE_JSON, expect_errors=True)
     assert response.status_code == 409
```

but when I run I get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: This Session's transaction has been rolled back due to a previous exception during flush. To begin a new transaction with this Session, first issue Session.rollback(). Original exception was: New instance <Device at 0x7fb5e83d5d68> with identity key (<class 'complex_service.db.Device'>, ('1ec67df1-e673-4505-8e00-5be58ec1656a',)) conflicts with persistent instance <Device at 0x7fb5e84419e8>
```

together with

```
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.FlushError: New instance <Device at 0x7fb5e83d5d68> with identity key (<class 'complex_service.db.Device'>, ('1ec67df1-e673-4505-8e00-5be58ec1656a',)) conflicts with persistent instance <Device at 0x7fb5e84419e8>
```

even if I do not pass the fixture inside the test and instead I do a double request, it doesn't work, failing with the same error

```
def test_create_device_fail(single_device, application):
     application.post_json('/api/v1/device', params=DEVICE_JSON, expect_errors=True)
     assert response.status_code == 200
     response = application.post_json('/api/v1/device', params=DEVICE_JSON, expect_errors=True)
     assert response.status_code == 409
```

Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: Not sure how exactly pytest works, but it seems that in `single_device()` you add the device, then at `yield` you enter the test? You should probably leave the app context before you yield, and then enter it again to delete the devices after the test.

Comment: making the fixture like this:

`@pytest.yield_fixture(scope='function')
def single_device(application):
    obj = Device(**DEVICE_JSON)
    with application.current_app_context():
        db.session.add(obj)
        db.session.commit()
     yield obj
    with application.current_app_context():
        for device in Device.query.all():
            db.session.delete(device)
        db.session.commit()`

I get a new error:

`sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError: Instance <Device at 0x7fab4e154ef0> is not bound to a Session; attribute refresh operation cannot proceed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @lyschoening advice I managed to get it working,

```
@pytest.yield_fixture(scope='function')
def single_device(application):
    obj = Device(**DEVICE_JSON)
    with application.current_app_context():
        db.session.add(obj)
        db.session.commit()
    yield None
    with application.current_app_context():  
        for device in Device.query.all():
            db.session.delete(device)
        db.session.commit()
```

So basically not yielding the object to the test and having 2 different application contexts